# Ajuda na Checkbox em C#

Tags: c#, checkbox

Tenho este código.

```
private void Verificar()
{
    mUpdater = new DatabaseUpdaterService();

    mUpdater.Initialize(false, null);

    DataTable dt = mUpdater.GetVersionCheckBoxToUpdate();
    int h = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Text = row["Version"].ToString();
        cb.Name = row["Version"].ToString();
        cb.Checked = false;
        cb.Parent = this;
        cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, h);
        h += cb.Height;
        cb.CheckedChanged += Cb_CheckedChanged;
        cb.Show();

    }
 }

void Cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            

}
```

O objetivo é, quando selecionar as *checkbox*, quero que passe o conteúdo dela, para  mais tarde poder fazer o *update* das que eu selecionei. 
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Ana seja bem vinda ao Stack Overflow. Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Poderia explicar melhor o que deseja fazer? Recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre o site.

Comment: Apresente mais informações para que a comunidade possa ajudar você.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis o código:

```
    private void Verificar()
    {
        mUpdater = new DatabaseUpdaterService();

        mUpdater.Initialize(false, null);

        DataTable dt = mUpdater.GetVersionCheckBoxToUpdate();
        int h = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Text = row["Version"].ToString();
            cb.Name = row["Version"].ToString();
            cb.Checked = false;
            cb.Parent = this;
            cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, h);
            h += cb.Height;
            cb.CheckedChanged += Cb_CheckedChanged;
            cb.Show();

        }
    }

    void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sender é o objeto CheckBox onde o evento ocorreu
        CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox)sender);
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            string versao = cb.Name;
            //Faz o processamento que deseja
        }

    }
```

Uma observação é que esse processamento dentro do evento irá ocorrer toda vez que for marcado o checkbox. Talvez fosse o caso de você percorrer a tela na hora do Insert/Update e assim pegar todos os valores que estão checados.

Segue código, mais extenso porém acho mais adequado ao caso:

```
    List<string> versoesSelecionadas;
    private void Verificar()
    {
        mUpdater = new DatabaseUpdaterService();

        mUpdater.Initialize(false, null);

        DataTable dt = mUpdater.GetVersionCheckBoxToUpdate();
        int h = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Text = row["Version"].ToString();
            cb.Name = row["Version"].ToString();
            cb.Checked = false;
            cb.Parent = this;
            cb.Tag = "esseCBfoiCriadoNoMetodoVerificar";
            cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, h);
            h += cb.Height;
            cb.Show();

        }
    }
    private void LerCheckBox(Control ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                string tag = c.Tag == null ? "" : c.Tag.ToString();
                if (tag == "esseCBfoiCriadoNoMetodoVerificar")
                {
                    //Aqui você já tem um objeto CheckBox criado no método verificar
                    if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
                    {
                        string versao = ((CheckBox)c).Name;
                        //A Versao "versao" está marcada como true
                        versoesSelecionadas.Add(versao);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (c.HasChildren)
            {
                LerCheckBox(c);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Gravar()
    {
        versoesSelecionadas = new List<string>();

        LerCheckBox(this);

        foreach (string v in versoesSelecionadas)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(v + " foi selecionada");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Já consegui, obrigada a todos :)

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi sua pergunta muito bem, mas pelo que entendi, você pode fazer isso:

```
void Cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (Cb_Checked)
    {
        Verificar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta está controversa. Você diz que não entendeu, e pelo que entendeu, apresenta uma resposta. Talvez o caminho fosse solicitar mais informações.

Comment: Ele disse que não entendeu muito bem, pois a questão não está totalmente clara, mas pelo que ele entendeu, se foi exatamente o que ele entendeu esse código pode ajudar, não vejo "controversa" nessa resposta. E se isso for exatamente o que soluciona o problema?